# If variable matches another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var test = "Example";
var another = "Example";

<div id="whatever">
 Blah
</div>
```

How can I apply `$('#whatever').hide()` if `test` and `another` match, and `$('#whatever').css('color','red')` if they don't?

Comment: Really, you couldn't figure this out? Did you try to run the code before document ready or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(test === another){
       $('#whatever').hide();
    }else{
       $('#whatever').css('color','red');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else):

```
if(test == another)
    $('#whatever').hide();
else
    $('#whatever').css('color','red');
```